# Cursive text in a text field using HTML

Tags: html

Probably a very simple question:

I have this code

```
 <tr>
     <td><b>Item name:</b></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="Receptnr" value="Enter values here"></td>
 </tr>
```

I would then like the part "Enter values here" to be cursive, but I can't figure out to get just that part cursive.

Is there a very simple way to do it?

thx :)

Comment: Would you like the whole text to be cursive or just placeholder?

Comment: @Stichoza — What placeholder?

Comment: Do you want "Enter values here" to be cursive and then the user input regular non-cursive? or everything (including users' entered text)?

Comment: Only the "Enter values here". Users entered text should be normal

Comment: a clearer question would have specified that the placeholder text should be cursive, however, the user input text should not be affected by this style change. Answered/clarified within the comments isn't a best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, most of these answers lead you to styling the whole input, which I don't think is what you want. You need javascript to style the default value only, and then change it back to "normal", for example like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name_here" size="20" value="default_value" style="color:red;" onfocus="if (this.value == 'default_value') {this.value=''; this.style.color='blue';}" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CQ58j/

Comment: A CLEARER question would have avoided the less than perfect answers though.

Comment: Well, it wasn't that unclear. People just try to be super fast and get their answer up to get points, which is the real problem, as they don't really think before they answer...

Comment: @Phlume: how would you have asked the question then?

Comment: @user3374439 You could have mentioned the word "default value". Nevertheless, I got it at first read.

Comment: I feel that javascript is unnecessary for something that can be so easily achieved with CSS. What would your reasoning be for JS?

Comment: @Guy, I wrote an answer with CSS only and working demo. I got downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough:

```
input{
    font-style: italic;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PSTN3/

Comment: I assume your jsfiddle is supposed to have something on it, but it's just a new fiddle. Or you could just be pointing him to use it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about this would be to use placeholders and then style them. If you modified your HTML to something like this, changing the `value` attribute to `placeholder`:

```
<tr>
     <td><b>Item name:</b></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="Receptnr" placeholder="Enter values here"></td>
 </tr>
```

Then you can use this css, where 'cursive-font' would be the name of your cursive font. if you are using a custom font you will also need to add the font using @font-face:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   font-family:'cursive-font', serif;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   font-family:'cursive-font', serif;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   font-family:'cursive-font', serif;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   font-family:'cursive-font', serif; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to style the input tag. You can do it inline:
   `<input type="text" name="Receptnr" value="Enter values here" style='font-style: italic;' />`

or in a CSS section

```
input {font-style: italic;}
```

Comment: try to avoid inline if you can. Styles with styles. markup with markup

Answer (score -1):

Use you own vendor-specific prefixes...

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   font-style:italic;
}
```

Edit:
Use "placeholder" instead of "value". It is the reason why it is in HTML5.